# Reading and updating 10 data records (tuples) in MySql Table at the same time(Using a single query);

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to read 10 records from a MySql table and updating a field IsRead to 1 to avoid the duplicate read. So when I again read the data then the next 10 record should be read not the already read records using IsRead,

> > select * from tablename where IsRead=0 limit 10;

But my Question is how can I read and update the 10 records at the same time.

Using a Single Query.

**EDIT**

Previously I am reading and updating one one records, but now I want to avoid the reading time (once for reading and once for updating) so what will be the suitable way to read and update 10 records. Duplicate record should not be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is not a single statement, but transactions.

Transactions are a way to make multiple statements [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant. Read about it in the link provided. In short it means, "all or nothing".

Code wise it would simply look something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
select * from tablename where IsRead=0 ORDER BY created_or_whatever_column limit 10 for update;
update tablename set IsRead = 1 ORDER BY created_or_whatever_column LIMIT 10;
COMMIT;
```

Notice, that I added an `order by` clause. Using `limit` without `order by` doesn't make sense. There's no order in the data in a database, unless you specify it.

Also I added `for update` to the `select` statement, so the rows are locked until the transaction ends (with `commit`) so that no other transaction manipulates these rows in the meantime.

What you should also have a look at in this context are the [isolation levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_level).

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine :)