# Concurrent reading and updating data in Mule

Tags: sql, architecture, mule

I am referring to a situation like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570618/reading-and-updating-10-data-records-tuples-in-mysql-table-at-the-same-timeus). I need to read data from a table where user keeps adding data to the table.
Look up the table( may be hourly or by 15 minutes etc), if there is a record, read data and update the table status to "reading done". Now process the data to upload to PAAS application, once it uploads to PAAS, then update the status to "processed to pass". i.e

Step 1: Determine if there is any data to pick up.

Step 2: Mark rows for reading and update table status to reading done

Step 3: Pick up data.

Step 4: After successfully sending the data to PAAS provider, mark the rows as processed by update query.

As this is done with ACID behavior, I am using Mule to develop this. My questions are:

1) Can I handle in Mule? Does Mule support this concurrency functionality?

2) Should I develop this in ORM tools like Hibernate/JPA with Mule to handle this?

3) How can I use any messaging services like AMQP broker if that helps better?

Using Mule 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, Mule supports all that you mentioned, and you can have concurrent messages being processed at the same time in Mule.

2) Depends on how complex your queries / data structures are but typically you would use normal SQL queries in the Database connector.

3) There is an AMQP transports available that you can use to connect to AMQP brokers such as RabbitMQ or SwiftMQ. You can find more info on this connector, along with examples here: https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/amqp-integration-connector

HTH